# Find and Insert Rows for Missing Timestamps, Remove rows for Unwanted Timestamps

Tags: excel, timestamp, vba

I have a huge table containing about 24000 rows of 800 hours of data, where each cell has an interval of 2 minutes. The sample values in table are:

```
station,  date,             used, free
1,        5/21/2008 12:00   6     15
1,        5/21/2008 12:02,  7,    14
1,        5/21/2008 12:04,  6,    15
1,        5/21/2008 12:08,  5,    16
1,        5/21/2008 12:14,  6,    15
1,        5/21/2008 12:15,  7,    14
1,        5/21/2008 12:16,  7,    14
```

In the above table, time-stamps for 12:06, 12:10 and 12:12 are missing, while 12:15 should not be there, because every interval should be of 2 minutes.
I tried the following code provided by rbrhodes at the following link:

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/85157-insert-fill-missing-rows-within-sequential-dates-times-list

Code:
    Option Explicit

```
Sub rowinsert()

Dim ThisTime As Double
Dim NextTime As Double
Dim cel As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rval As Variant

'Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Get last row of data
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Where to look
Set rng = Range("B1:B" & LastRow)

'Chek all
For Each cel In rng
'Check if done
If cel.Offset(1, 0) = vbNullString Then GoTo endo
'Add 15 mins to cell value
ThisTime = Round((cel + TimeValue("00:02:00")) * 24 * 30) / 30 / 24
'Get next cel time
NextTime = Round(cel.Offset(1, 0) * 24 * 30) / 30 / 24
'Check if time is + 2
If ThisTime <> NextTime Then
'No. Insert a row
cel.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
'Put next req'd time
cel.Offset(1, 0) = ThisTime
'Put 'N/A'
Range(cel.Offset(1, 1), cel.Offset(1, 2)) = "N/A"
End If
Next

endo:

'Cleanup
Set cel = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing

'Reset
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It is working perfectly fine for missing values. but if there are timestamps in sequence like 12:14, 12:15, 12:16, then that code is not working.

I need to modify the code to delete the rows which contains "odd" timestamps.
This my first time experience with VBA. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've got this line that is working for the missing values

```
If ThisTime <> NextTime Then 
   cel.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
```

but there isn't a line to remove the ones that you don't want. Like

```
If NextTime < 00:02 Then    '<<---I'm not sure if the time format is correct
   cel.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
```

Or you might have to use

```
If NextTime - ThisTime < 00:02 Then
   cel.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
```

And I don't understand the "add 15 minutes" comment when you are adding what looks like 2 minutes. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have spent a whole day but couldn't make it to work. I have also tried things like: 
If (NextTime - ThisTime) < Round(TimeValue("00:02:00")) Then
            cel.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If  But I don't know that what should be used there.

Comment: Hi. I have solved it by extracting the minutes as integer and checking if it is odd number. Anyways, thanks a lot @Mitch

Comment: @SorathAsnani LOL, I worked on it for quite a while Saturday, but got busy at work, so I wasn't able to get it done. Working with times can be quite a challenge sometimes. Glad you got it ! Thanks for the vote up !